# CloudKit Push Notifications to another user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, cloudkit

I have a game that is currently running on Parse.com and I am looking to transfer it over to Apple's CloudKit. In the game, if a user challenges another user it sends that user a Push Notification to let them know. Is this possible with CloudKit's subscription notification method or should I use a different Push Notification provider that can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by letting every user create a subscription to a message recordType where the 'to' field is for that user. Then when you create an invite for that user you set the 'to' field and that user will get a notification.